# como acceder a una parte de mi array con javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy creando una lista de productos pero lo que necesito después es solo acceder a una parte de esa lista de productos que tengo hecha con javascript en este caso solo quiero el id del producto estoy realizándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
   function listarProductos(){
       var listaProductos = [];
       var descripcion = $('.agregarProducto');
       var cantidad = $('.nuevaCantidadProducto');
       var precio = $('.nuevoPrecioProducto');
       for(var i = 0; i < descripcion.length; i++){
           listaProductos.push({"id":$(descripcion[i]).attr("idProducto"),
                                "descripcion":$(descripcion[i]).val(),
                                "cantidad":$(cantidad[i]).val(),
                                "stock":$(cantidad[i]).attr("nuevostock"),
                                "precio":$(precio[i]).attr("precioReal"),
                                "total":$(precio[i]).val()})
       }
       $("#listaProductos").val(JSON.stringify(listaProductos));
       console.log(listaProductos[id]);
   }
```

como verán al final trato de hacer algo como `console.log(listaProductos[id]);` para que en consola solo me arroje el id de esa lista ero creo que no es una forma correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listaProductos` es un arreglo, este debe ser accedido utilizando índices numéricos:

```js
listaProductos[0]
listaProductos[1]
...etc
```

Una vez accedes a un elemento en una posición debes ver qué propiedades son accesibles a este elemento, como en tu caso estás accediendo a un objeto tienes  dos formas de acceder a sus propiedades:

**Primera forma:**

```js
listProductos[0].id;
```

**Segunda forma:**

```js
listProductos[0]['id'];
```

Nota como en la segunda forma se requieren las comillas `"` o `'` (dobles o simples) para acceder a la propiedad, no puedes acceder con una variable a menos que la variable sea estrictamente un `string`, así;

**Tercera forma**

```js
const nombreDeLaLlaveId = 'id'
listProductos[0][nombreDeLaLlaveId];
```

Comment: habrá alguna forma de recorrer todo mi arreglo sin repetir los valores, ya que cuando quiero acceder a todos los valores de id se me repiten algunos varias veces.